# Does $\int_{1}^{\infty} g(x)\ dx$ imply $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}g(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Let $g:[1, \infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ a continuous non-negative function, such that $\int_{1}^{\infty} g(x)\ dx$ converges.
Is it true that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}g(x)=0$ ?

I tried to find a counter-example but I can't figure a trivial one.
I also tried to prove it by the definition of the convergence of $g(x)$ but couldn't show that limit is really $0$.

Comment: You mean $ x \rightarrow +\infty $?

Comment: @FreeSalad Yes, I meant that. Sorry.

Comment: It's true if you also force $g$ to be monotonic.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)\,dx$ is known to converge.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $\sin(x^2)$ is not non-negative however.

Comment: @Zubzub: quite right, I missed that.

Comment: I remember this one. And I remember I didn't really find an expression but got it right anyway. Hope it's really identical :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a function made up of triangles (i.e. it starts at $0$, it goes to $1$, then comes back at $0$). Make it so that the area of each triangle is $1/n^2$ (i.e. the base of each triangle is $2/n^2$).

This means that $$\int_1^\infty g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$ converges.

But the limit of $g(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ is not $0$ as $g(x)$ alternates between $0$ and $1$

Comment: Is this continous?

Comment: @Dror It clearly is. All the triangles are "connected".

Comment: Whoops my bad..

Comment: So is it true to say that if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}g(x)$ exists, then it must be zero?

Comment: @z00x Yes; if the limit is $l > 0$ then you can bound the integral with something like $\int_1^R g(x)dx \ge l/2\cdot R$, which diverges as $R \to \infty$, which implies that the integral $\int_1^\infty g(x)dx$ does not converge. So if the limit exists then it must be $0$